# How to fix this PlayerNotificationManager.createWithNotificationChannel error

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

[image]

I am developing a music app but i am getting error can anybody tell me how to fix this `PlayerNotificationManager.createWithNotificationChannel`?

`.createWithNotificationChannel` is not recognizable

```
class MusicNotificationManager(
    private val context: Context,
    sessionToken: MediaSessionCompat.Token,
    notificationListener: PlayerNotificationManager.NotificationListener,
    private val newSongCallback: () -> Unit
) {
    //creating notification for music player
    private val notificationManager: PlayerNotificationManager

    init {
        val mediaController = MediaControllerCompat(context, sessionToken)
        notificationManager = PlayerNotificationManager.createWithNotificationChannel(
            context,
            NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID,
            R.string.notification_channel_name,
            R.string.notification_channel_description,
            NOTIFICATION_ID,
            DescriptionAdapter(mediaController),
            notificationListener
        ).apply{
            setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_music)
            setMediaSessionToken(sessionToken)
        }
    }

    fun showNotification(player: Player){
        notificationManager.setPlayer(player)
    }
    //get current playing song
    private inner class DescriptionAdapter(
        private val mediaController: MediaControllerCompat
    ): PlayerNotificationManager.MediaDescriptionAdapter {
        override fun getCurrentContentTitle(player: Player): CharSequence {
            newSongCallback()
            return mediaController.metadata.description.title.toString()

        }

        override fun createCurrentContentIntent(player: Player): PendingIntent? {
            return mediaController.sessionActivity
        }
        //get current playing song title
        override fun getCurrentContentText(player: Player): CharSequence? {
            return mediaController.metadata.description.subtitle.toString()
        }
        //get current playing song icon
        override fun getCurrentLargeIcon(
            player: Player,
            callback: PlayerNotificationManager.BitmapCallback
        ): Bitmap? {
            Glide.with(context).asBitmap()
                .load(mediaController.metadata.description.iconUri)
                .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>(){
                    override fun onResourceReady(
                        resource: Bitmap,
                        transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?
                    ) {
                        callback.onBitmap(resource)
                    }

                    override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) = Unit
                })
            return null
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to add all possible dependencies in my build.gradle file but not able to resolve this issue.

Comment: Let's see your dependencies in `build.gradle`

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEgbi.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivxnb.png

Answer (score 12):

`PlayerNotificationManager.createWithNotificationChannel()` is deprecated. Here is how you can achieve the same functionality:

```
private val notificationManager: PlayerNotificationManager  

Use Builder 
   init {
        val mediaController = MediaControllerCompat(context, sessionToken)

        notificationManager = PlayerNotificationManager.Builder(
            context,
            NOTIFICATION_ID, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setChannelNameResourceId(R.string.notification_Channel_name)
           .setChannelDescriptionResourceId(R.string.notification_Channel_Description)
            .setMediaDescriptionAdapter(DescriptionAdapter(mediaController))
            .setNotificationListener(notificationListener)
            .build()

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
init {
        val mediaController = MediaControllerCompat(context, sessionToken)
        notificationManager = PlayerNotificationManager.Builder(
            context,
            NOTIFICATION_ID, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID
        )
            .setChannelNameResourceId(R.string.notification_channel_name)
            .setChannelDescriptionResourceId(R.string.notification_channel_description)
            .setMediaDescriptionAdapter(DescriptionAdapter(mediaController))
            .setNotificationListener(notificationListener)
            .build()
            .apply {
                setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_music)
                setMediaSessionToken(sessionToken)
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

PlayerNotificationManager.createWithNotificationChannel were deprecated in favor of PlayerNotificationManager.Builder

refer

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/92e05bcd6608b48cc4d20974f55e6a9136274c33/library/ui/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlayerNotificationManager.java#L717-L719

use

`public Builder(Context context,int notificationId,String channelId,MediaDescriptionAdapter mediaDescriptionAdapter)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example.

```
playerNotificationManager = new PlayerNotificationManager.Builder(this, 151, "1234")
            .setMediaDescriptionAdapter(new PlayerNotificationManager.MediaDescriptionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public CharSequence getCurrentContentTitle(Player player) {
                    return videoTitle;
                }

                @Nullable
                @Override
                public PendingIntent createCurrentContentIntent(Player player) {
                    return null;
                }

                @Nullable
                @Override
                public CharSequence getCurrentContentText(Player player) {
                    return null;
                }

                @Nullable
                @Override
                public Bitmap getCurrentLargeIcon(Player player, PlayerNotificationManager.BitmapCallback callback) {
                    if (!VideoPlayerActivity.this.isDestroyed()) {
                        Glide.with(VideoPlayerActivity.this)
                                .asBitmap()
                                .load(new File(mVideoFiles.get(position).getPath()))
                                .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {

                                    }
                                    @Override
                                    public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

                                    }
                                });

                    }
                    return null;
                }
            }).build();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

It works by changing the implementation from 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.15.0' to

implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.11.6'